# Generating a audio waveform graphic within Python

Tags: python, audio, waveform

Is it possible? I'd like run over a batch of audio files and produce graphic waveform files from them. Similar to what SoundCloud displays, but perhaps the module(s) im seeking will offer a few more options.

Whats out there? whats good?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Audio waveform visualisation in Python/Django](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3290054/audio-waveform-visualisation-in-python-django)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

See [this example](https://web.archive.org/web/20161203074728/http://jaganadhg.freeflux.net:80/blog/archive/2009/09/09/plotting-wave-form-and-spectrogram-the-pure-python-way.html), it is exactly what you want in pure Python. You have [another options](http://blog.freesound.org/?p=10) too, but using `audiolab`.